# Star in another's favorite list is not clickable

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, bookmarks

If you open any other (not yours) user profile and make a switch to favorite tab, the star on the left of each item looks clickable (according to the cursor style as "hand"), but actually it doesn't:

> [image: unclickable star]

This is slightly confusing behaviour.